# Lambdafunction to copy from one S3 to another S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, function

While  trying to implement S3 to s3 copy by using Lambda function I am getting below error.

> **"errorType": "AttributeError",   "stackTrace": [
> "  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 6, in lambda_handler\n    file_name=event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name\n**

Below is the code.

```
import boto3 def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #file_name=event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name   
    service_name='s3'
    region_name='us-east-2'
    aws_access_key_id=''
    aws_secret_access_key=''
    s3=boto3.resource(
    service_name=service_name,
    region_name=region_name,
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
    )
    copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'lamdbasourcebucket', 
    'Key': file_name
    }
    bucket_name = 'lambdatargetbucket2022'
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source,bucket_name,file_name)
```

Can anyone help me on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: It looks like the error is raised from the commented line `file_name=event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name`. The correct way to access is `event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']`. Are you sure the code is saved?

Comment: Needs to be saved and deployed.